# Create a point in a given image on a webpage

Tags: javascript, php, image

Let's say I have [this](http://www.delhitourism.gov.in/delhitourism/images/india_map.jpg) map displayed in a webpage.
What's the best way to let a user of this page to click and, on mouse click, generate a point similar to [this](http://www.mattplapp.com/wpcore/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/Bullseye1-300x300.jpg).
I have some knowledge in html and php, a bit less in javascript but I can do fine.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to detect mouse coordinates:

```
 $('img').click(function (e) {
      var offset = $(this).offset();
      var xPos = e.clientX - offset.left;
      var yPos = e.clientY - offset.top;
  });
```

Where `xPos` and `yPos` are coordinates of clicked point.

Then you need to put your point on clicked position:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img').click(function (e) {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var xPos = e.clientX - offset.left;
        var yPos = e.clientY - offset.top;

        $('.container').append('<span class="point"></span>');
        $('.point:last-child').css({
            'top': yPos,
            'left': xPos
        });
    });
});
```

**Check out this fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/zur4ik/mcdvd/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can edit this script

http://www.chestysoft.com/imagefile/javascript/get-coordinates.asp

Comment: I'll give it a shot, thanks. Anyway, if someone else knows other way to do it, feel free to answer. Thanks